# At which point does the inner solar system end and the outer solar system start

Tags: solar-system, asteroid-belt

I've heard how the inner solar system ends at the asteroid belt but where in the asteroid belt?The start?The middle?The end?Is there an exact distance that is put in place?

Comment: So far as Sci Fi goes,  it's definitely the Asteroid Belt.  Mars & Venus are "close enough" to make real-world spaceship drives acceptable means of transport.  If you're going to colonize moons of Jupiter, then you need either suspended animation or Epstein Drives (at the very least, if not magic reactionless drives)

Comment: @Carl Witthoft  What about atomic rockets, or nuclear pulse propulsion (as proposed in Project Orion)?  They seem to be a lot more real world than supsended animatin, Epstein Drives, or magic reactionless drives.